# MathJax not rendering correctly on full site on mobile.

Tags: bug, mathjax

When I use mse on my phone I always use the full site because personally I hate the mobile one. This has been a good experience before and I had no problem with mathjax rendering latex incorrectly. Until around the time the site changed to a newer version of mathjax. Now most (not all) math becomes scrambled and extremely difficult to read. I had ignored this problem for a while hoping for a fix however I could not find any discussion on the topic.

[image]
[image]
[image]

There a many many more examples (even worse ones) showing this behavior. So can this be fixed or prevented?

---

My phone is a Moto G running Android 4.4.4

Comment: I faced the same issue today, on Nexus 7 tab.

Comment: @Alizter Please specify what system you're running.

Comment: I have no problem on my Samsung Galaxy S3mini or my Samsung GalaxyTab 10.1.

Comment: One year has passed, but I still see the same rendering problem on multiple Android devices.